# How to make an image size responsive within a td tag?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've got an image within a relatively complex table structure and inside a td tag. I'm trying to make the image response so that when the page is viewed on mobile, the image is slightly scaled down vs. when viewed on a desktop i.e. ideally, I want it to be 50% of the width page.

I've tried adding a `max-width` on the `img` tag as well as the `tg` tag outside it and neither appeared to work.

My code:

```html
<html>
  <table bgcolor="#efefef" width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td valign="top">
              <![endif]-->
              <table width="100%" class="maxW" style="max-width: 600px; margin: auto;" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" align="center">
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                          <table width="94%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding-bottom:10px">
                            <tr>...</tr>
                            <tr>...</tr>
                            <tr>...</tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                          <table width="94%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding-bottom:10px">
                            <tr>...</tr>
                            <tr>...</tr>
                            <tr>...</tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" valign="middle" style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #353535; padding:3%; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px;">
                          .........
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding:1%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px;"><a href="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" style="max-width: 50%"></img></a></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <![endif]-->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `display:inline-block` for every column in your table. It will make the columns shift below each column when width of the screen decreases and make tr `text-align: center;`

Comment: I wonder if you have to only use td . What about using div element instead of table with flex grid layout